# Cauchy Surface and topological structure

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, time, topology, causality

I heard in passing a result that if a connected spacetime without boundary admits a cauchy surface $\mathcal{S}$, then the manifold is topologically tubular, i.e. $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{S} \times \mathbb{R}$. Is this true?

Moreover, does this result follow for manifolds with boundary? There are two cases I can think of:

1. If the spacetime $\mathcal{M}$ has a single boundary and admits a Cauchy surface, do we have that $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{S} \times [0,\infty)$.
2. If the spacetime $\mathcal{M}$ has a boundary consisting of two disjoint spacelike-separated hypersurfaces, do we have that $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{S} \times [0,1]$.

Are either of these statements true?

Disclaimer: I'm not a physicist, I've just done a bit of differential geometry, but causality interests me so I would like to know more.

Comment: It feels like [math.se] is probably a better home for this question ─ I don't really see the physics here.

Comment: After some more research I've found that this is Geroch's Splitting Theorem, so the question I'm asking is whether this applies to spacetimes with boundary as well. This is physics..?

Comment: It's difficult for me to envision how a manifold with boundary could contain a Cauchy surface, unless the boundary *is* the Cauchy surface.  For example, the piece of Minkowski space $0 \leq x \leq 1$ does not have a Cauchy surface.  however, the piece of Minkowski space $0 \leq t \leq 1$ *does* have a Cauchy surface, namely any value $t = \text{const.}$ (including the spacetime boundaries $t = 0$ and $t = 1$.)